# LINQ to Entities returning NULL when searching by GUID

Tags: entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have a LINQ to Entities Query that is suppose to return a specific resultset based on the GUID provided.

```
    [OperationContract, WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public List<OrderDetails> GetOrderDetailsByGUID(Guid OrderID)
    {
        var listit =(from OV in EC.OrderProductVariants
                join O in EC.Orders on OV.OrderId equals O.Id
                join PV in EC.ProductVariants on OV.ProductVariantId equals PV.Id
                join P in EC.Products on PV.ProductId equals P.Id
                join CT in EC.Customers on O.CustomerId equals CT.Id
                join AD in EC.Addresses on CT.BillingAddress_Id equals AD.Id
                where O.OrderGuid == OrderID
                select new OrderDetails
                {
                    OrderID = O.OrderGuid,
                    Company = AD.Company,
                    ShippingMethod = O.ShippingMethod,
                    Product = P.Name,
                    QuantityOnOrder = OV.Quantity
                }
                    ).ToList();

        return listit;
    }
```

It Returns NULL, can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly returns as NULL?

Comment: The entire statement. I checked there is a valid record in the SQL Database for any given GUID. Let me post the entire method

Comment: Honestly I'm surprised if `ToList()` can return `null`, it's not documented to. Do you mean that it's returning en empty `List`?

Comment: Yup pretty much stumped myself.. Checked my Console in Chrome, Firefox, and added break point to method. No errors. Ran Fiddler and the query does not time out or anything funny like that

Comment: It is probably one of the joins filtering it out. Try removing all the joins, then add them back in one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All solution that could work in a scenario like this is to create a view and do just a one liner code to access it

```
var q = EC.OrderProductVariants.SingleOrDefault(u => u.OrderGuid.Equals(guid));
```